# Change the separator sign in tcolorbox predefined theorem styles while preserving the other properties

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I am currently using tcolorbox in my math notes, and I have defined the following environment for theorems.

```
\newtcbtheorem{defn}{}{
enhanced, 
breakable,
colback = BrightGreen!50!white,
colframe = white, 
coltitle = ForestGreen,
sharp corners,
theorem style = break,
fonttitle = \bfseries\large,
separator sign = {.~}
}{defn}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=defn]{thm}{}{
enhanced, 
breakable,
colback = cyan!30!white, 
colframe = white,
coltitle = RoyalBlue,
sharp corners,
theorem style = break,
fonttitle = \bfseries\large,
separator sign = {.~}
}{thm}
```

The result is some thing like this.

[image]

I actually want to remove the `(:` separator sign, which is (probably?) defined as a part of the predefined `break` theorem style. The result should somehow like this:

[image]

How would I be able to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses around the title are due to the style you chose.
Just don't use `theorem style = break` and modify a little your `\newtcbtheorem` definition.

I added `theorem number` for the correct positioning of the theorem number. An updated version of `tcolorbox` is needed to use this option. I'm using 5.0.2.

Since you didn't provide a complete MWE, I used `book` as document class and I invented the `BrightGreen` color.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{BrightGreen}{rgb}{0.4, 1.0, 0.0}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{commonstyle/.style={
    enhanced, 
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    toptitle=4pt,
    bottomtitle=0pt,
    titlerule=0pt,
    top=4pt,
    fonttitle = \bfseries\large,
    separator sign = {.},
    theorem number
    }}

\newtcbtheorem{defn}{}{
    commonstyle,
    colback = BrightGreen!50!white,
    colbacktitle = BrightGreen!50!white, 
    colframe = BrightGreen!50!white,
    coltitle = ForestGreen,
    }{defn}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=defn]{thm}{}{
    commonstyle,
    colback = cyan!30!white, 
    colbacktitle = cyan!30!white, 
    colframe = cyan!30!white,
    coltitle = RoyalBlue,
    }{thm}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{My Chapter}
    \section{My Section}
    \begin{defn}{The title of my definition}{}
        The text of my definition.
    \end{defn}
    \begin{thm}{The title of my theorem}{}
        The text of my theorem.
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]